# Why are my npm_modules folders all highlighted red in VS Code?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, node-modules, create-react-app

I recently cloned a React repository (based off of `create-react-app`) from BitBucket. Why are all my node_modules folders highlighted red in Visual Studio Code?

I ran `npm install`, `npm update`, and `npm start` and didn't run into any errors, but the folders are still highlighted red. How can I make sure these packages are being installed/updated properly?

[image: red node_modules folder screenshot]

Comment: Looks like this is a problem for others -- see some of the last comments on this thread: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/782

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer posted here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54574

> **Last post on the above thread:** "This unrelated to intellisense. It is caused by cobalt2 theme which—from what I can tell at least—decided to color .gitignored files as red. You can disable explorer colorization this by setting `"explorer.decorations.colors": false`"

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color of ignored files in VS Code settings (*darker gray works nicely for me*):

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Cobalt2]": {
      "gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#808080",
    }
  },
```

[image: ignored git files image]